# Why creating a new Component class for redux connect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In reference this coding pattern:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Thing from '../components/Thing';

class ThingContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Thing {...this.props} />;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ThingContainer);
```

So it 1) imports a component(Thing), 2) creates another component (ThingContainer which is technically not a container) class to render that first component, and lastly using connect to finally export the container.

What's the difference with skipping step 2 above, and simply using the imported component(Thing) directly to export the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that file looks like it's somewhat unnecessary.  The `class ThingContainer` component does nothing but forward props to `<Thing>`, which is exactly what the wrapper components generated by `connect` do already.  So, that's useless - the file should just do `export default connect(mapState)(Thing)`, and it would work exactly the same without the extra `ThingContainer` definition.